# Show PopUpWindow at the top of Soft Keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, popupwindow, android-popupwindow

I'm trying to show my PopUpWindow at the top of my edittext (with softkeyboard present) how can i do that? Consider my EditText has `android:maxLines="5"` and Y position is not always the same. This is what i got so far...

```
private void createPopUpWindow() {
    View newView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView(); // this = activity

    int[] loc = new int[2];
    pivot.getLocationInWindow(loc);
    int topOfPivot = loc[1];

    Integer positionY = topOfPivot;
    popupWindow.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(newView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, positionY);

    frameLayout.getForeground().setAlpha(15);
    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
}
```

Any suggestions?

[image: Here is a little bit up]

[image: What am i doing wrong?]

Comment: You maybe better off just putting a layout at the bottom of the page if you detect the keyboard is up. When the keyboard comes up your app is automatically resized and `onConfigurationChanged` is called.

Comment: The thing is that the PopUpWindow is not always been showed, it will be shown depending of what is been typing, so onConfigurationChanged can't be the trigger, the trigger of the popupwindow is my editText.addTextChangedListener

Comment: ok. That's even easier then. You should be able to use a relative layout and just have this layout inside it `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` with height being `wrap_content`. Have this layout set `visibility="gone"` until your listener calls it.